# Weird effect with JFrame and Graphics

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Game extends JFrame {

    public Game() {
    setTitle("Worm Attack");
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300, 300);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Welcome to Worm Attck", 75, 75);
    }
}
```

I have this as a code to open a `JFrame` and say "Welcome to Worm attack." When it opens the window, I see through, and I can see my desktop.

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Answer (score 0):

This is because the paint process was interrupted.

Try adding the `super.paint` call at the beginning of the `paint` method:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawString("Welcome to Worm Attck", 75, 75);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have messed up the brackets somehow but that might just be the paste you made here (not sure so won't edit the question).

About the actual problem, you shouldn't overwrite the paint method, rather override the paintComponents() method :).

Read this on how to do painting in java : http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html :)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing, you should use setVisible after your `JFrame` is complete.

```
setTitle("Worm Attack");
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(300, 300);
setVisible(true);
```